# Why doesn't this break

Tags: java

My code below is from Oracle.

```
public class MyLoop {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String[] sa = {"tom ", "jerry "}; 
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      for(String s : sa) {
        System.out.print(x + " " + s);
        if(x == 1) break; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0 tom 0 jerry 1 tom 2 tom 2 jerry
> ```

I am learning java and I came across this. I don't understand why `1 tom` prints when the break is at `1`. If `1 tom` prints why then doesn't `1 jerry`?

Comment: because the break only breaks the next label... so the inner for-loop going over "tom" and "jerry".... Aside from that, explanations about code are off-topic here :( please take a [tour] and read the [help/on-topic]

Comment: Your code is sequential. Just draw out execution with a pencil.

Comment: It's correct: Iteration x = 0, s = tom, output 0tom. s=jerry output 0jerry. x=1 outout=1tom. then x it's exaclty 1 so break. x=2 same as x=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each value of `x` you're printing  the whole content of table `sa`, except for x == 1, where you're printing only the first value of sa : after printing this value, you're checking if x == 1 and then leave the inner loop and continue with next value of x.

Answer (score -1):

First check "x == 1" then print.

```
String[] sa = { "tom ", "jerry " };
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

    for (String s : sa) {
        if (x == 1) {
          break;
        }
        System.out.print(x + " " + s);

     }
}
```

Comment: @Vogel612 - This does not behave the same as OP's original code. (I don't think you meant to say that it does, but the wording of your comment might suggest so.) The problem with this answer is that it doesn't address OP's question, which is to explain why the original code behaves the way it does.